# Too slow movement despite enormous gravity in box2d

Tags: c#, xamarin, box2d

I'm playing around with box2d in CocosSharp. And I do have an issue - objects are moving too slowly! Despite of very big values...

```
// Physics
    public const float GRAVITY = -99999999999999999999999999999f;
    public const int PTM = 32;
    public const float ROCKET_MASS = 10000f;
    public const float TIMESTEP = 1f/240f;
```

Note that I've changed timestep. I'd tried to use mass, but it made absolytely no sense!

```
// Add rocket's physics
        var def = new b2BodyDef ();
        def.allowSleep = true;
        def.position = new b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
        def.type = b2BodyType.b2_dynamicBody;

        body = world.CreateBody (def);
        // body.Mass = Globals.ROCKET_MASS;
        body.SetActive(true);

        b2PolygonShape bodyBox = new b2PolygonShape();
        bodyBox.SetAsBox(0.1f , 0.5f);  // !

        b2FixtureDef bodyFixture = new b2FixtureDef();
        bodyFixture.shape = bodyBox;
        bodyFixture.density = 0.5f;
        bodyFixture.friction = 0.4f;

        body.CreateFixture(bodyFixture);
```

Here is how I initialize physics:

```
void InitPhysics ()
    {
        // Init the world
        var gravity = new b2Vec2 (0.0f, Globals.GRAVITY);
        world = new b2World (gravity);

        world.SetAllowSleeping (true);
        world.SetContinuousPhysics (true);

        // Now init the ground
        new Ground(world);
    }
```

And this is my Renderer code:

```
private void StartScheduling()
    {
        Schedule(t =>
            {
                if(t <= Globals.TIMESTEP)
                    timeAccumulator += t;
                else
                    timeAccumulator += Globals.TIMESTEP; 

                while (timeAccumulator >= Globals.TIMESTEP)
                {
                    world.Step(Globals.TIMESTEP, 6, 2);
                    timeAccumulator -= Globals.TIMESTEP;

                    // If touched, then do apply force
                    if (touch)
                    {
                        rocket.body.ApplyLinearImpulse(new b2Vec2(0f, 10000f), b2Vec2.Zero);
                    }

                    world.DrawDebugData();

                    rocket.UpdateRocketPosition();
                }

                world.ClearForces();
            });
    }
```

I'm so tired with it, please help! The rocket must fall quickly, but it does not!

Comment: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/gotchas#speedlimit

Comment: @iforce2d how can I decrease object's size in the box2d world, but saving it's visible size (i have 480x800 screen)?

Comment: Use a different value for PTM

Comment: @iforce2d it's never used in the code. Where should I place it?

Comment: ??? Just make all the values you use for Box2D dimensions smaller... it's not difficult.

Comment: @iforce2d if I make values smaller, the object wouldn't even move if speaking about gravity! It's alredy has 0,1 and 0,5 meters dimensions. What other values could be changed?

Comment: Those dimensions sound good. How are you determining that it does not move? Are you looking at the value returned by GetPosition()?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @iforce2d.

The solution is to adjust box2d units with PTM when rendering the result to the screen. As for me, I didn't understand, that box2d world is something very small and does not depends on device screen size, and that I should multiply it (enlarge) for rendering. Now it works pretty good:

```
public void UpdateRocketPosition ()
    {
        // PositionX, Y are sprite's positions
        PositionX = body.Position.x * Globals.PTM;
        PositionY = body.Position.y * Globals.PTM;
    }
```